# How to apply inverse text mask with CSS

Tags: html, css, mask, clipping

I'll try to explain my question with images. Here we go.

1 - This image shows the text masking an image, so far so good, I can do with the following code:

[image]

```
font-size: 120px;
background: url(image-to-be-masked.jpg) repeat 0 0, white;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

2 - This other image, the text creates the opposite effect, leaving transparent only the text area. This is what I want:

[image]

Has anyone tried it?

Comment: Are you going to have another image behind that? Why not just color the text in white?

Comment: Yes, there will be another image behind.

Comment: So you might want to try `-webkit-mask-image: url(the_bg_image.png);`

Comment: This is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think CSS can do that. But you can hack it together using three different nested elements:

- The outermost element contains the background-image
- The middle element contains the middle image
- The inner element contains the text, and has the same background image as the outermost element, masked with `background-clip:text;` like on your first example.

This works, but is a little cumbersome, as you'll have to compensate the masks background-position to achieve the desired effect. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dzkTE/.

Comment: Nice, this is a solution, but I don't know if it is the best. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the background image (or a gradient if its used) of the clipped text needs to have the exact same origin and sizing of the main image *in reference to the window*. This means it has to start outside of its own bounding box and sized greater than itself in order to get the backgrounds to line up correctly

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to achieve this with a couple of different methods.
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476482/2315496

See Below:

There are three ways to what you're looking for in HTML/CSS/JavaScript, some a little more hacky than others.

1. Use `<canvas>` to draw your shape and type, and set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation="xor";`where `ctx` is your canvas context.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "bold 36px Proxima Nova";
ctx.fillStyle='blue';
ctx.fillText("MORE",100,87);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='xor';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle='white';
ctx.arc(150,75,75,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
body{
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left,rgb(23, 39, 34) 4%,rgb(56, 99, 99) 37%,rgb(22, 27, 15) 73%,rgb(22, 27, 14) 93%,#232323 100%);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

html{
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

2. Use `mix-blend-mode: screen` and set the colour of the text to black.

```css
.blend-mode {
  background:white;
  border-radius:100%;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  line-height:155px;
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", Hevetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:36px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

body{
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left,rgb(23, 39, 34) 4%,rgb(56, 99, 99) 37%,rgb(22, 27, 15) 73%,rgb(22, 27, 14) 93%,#232323 100%);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

html{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blend-mode">MORE</div>
```

3. Use `-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent` and `-webkit-background-clip:text` to reveal a copy of the background behind it. This one requires some alignment of the background copy to match the 'original' background.

```css
.wrap{
  margin:20px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}

.background {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:4;
  
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index:5;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, rgb(23, 39, 34) 4%, rgb(56, 99, 99) 37%, rgb(22, 27, 15) 73%, rgb(22, 27, 14) 93%, #232323 100%);
  font-family: Proxima Nova, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

body{
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left,rgb(23, 39, 34) 4%,rgb(56, 99, 99) 37%,rgb(22, 27, 15) 73%,rgb(22, 27, 14) 93%,#232323 100%);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

html{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="text">MORE</div>
</div>
```

**None of these are likely to work that well cross browser, and I haven't tested them!**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure, I've added the content from the other post in here. Just didn't want to cross post.

Answer (score 3):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

header {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2017/17_04_art_bw_butterfly_bg.jpg) 50%/ cover
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    font: 900 35vmin/35vh cookie, cursive;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h2 contentEditable role='textbox' aria-multiline='true'>And stay alive...</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

[sorry i misread this. I tried out opposite, think :P]
I think you can do it by using background-clip.

```
background-clip:text;
```

check [here](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) (please try in chrome or add vendor prefixes). you can check [demo page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageUnderText/) form chris.

Comment: This is not the desired effect. Needs to be the oposite effect.

Comment: Look this new image(http://www.ricardomasao.com/temp/stackoverflow/stack03.jpg). This is the desired effect